# Cannot close two UiViewControllers

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I have a UiViewController **A** which opens a second UIViewController **B** as follows:

```
BViewController *BController = [Utilities getMainStoryBoardWithIdentifier:@"BViewController"];
[self presentViewController:webViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Now on UiViewController **B**, when I want to close it, I would like to close the **A** also. So I'm using the following:

```
[self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

But only the **B** is closing...

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

Can you please try following code :

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
[self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

Where `self` is your B controller. I've just tried the code and it works well. Tell me if any other help is needed.

Comment: Just tried, only the one on the top is dismissed, thanks anyway !

Comment: @HubertSolecki Can you please check my edit for tested code :)

Comment: @HubertSolecki Did you have time to try suggested code ? :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using an unwind segue.

If you have X which presents A, which in turn presents B, add

```
func unwindToX(_ segue: UIStoryboardSegue) { }
```

to view controller X

Then in your storyboard, drag from the close button in B to it's **exit** and select `unwindToX`. Clicking the button will then dismiss both view controllers. This also works with view controllers pushed on to a nav stack, or a combination of both.